# Firebase functions:shell < test.js example

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Firebase Functions has a few ways to test -- one being to run `firebase functions:shell` and provide objects manually. That's fine for simple things, but I'd like to pass in either a data file or a test file, ala `firebase functions:shell < test.js` from this old [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/09/testing-functions-locally-with-cloud.html)

Being unfamiliar with using node as a REPL or the special commands mentioned in this blog post, I've had trouble getting something to work.

I have a simplified trigger, that looks like:

```
export const onCreateUser = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{id}")
  .onCreate(async snapshot => {
    console.log("starting...");
    const data = snapshot.data() as UserDocumentData;
    console.log(data);
    
});
```

with a test.js that looks like:

```
var data = { foo: 123 };
onCreateUser(data);
```

running `firebase functions:shell < test.js` gives me some output, but skips over the `starting...` console.log section:

```
->firebase functions:shell < src/test.js
⚠  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "14"
i  functions: Loaded functions: onCreateUser
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services will affect production: firestore, database, pubsub
firebase > var data = { foo: 123 };
undefined
firebase > onCreateUser(data);
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > ⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Do I need to import the function in my test file, or am I missing something else? I'm looking for a faster way to do some basic integration testing.

This is in a typescript environment, if that matters.

Comment: Did you find out why this error was happening? I'm getting the same error when I execute `firebase functions:shell < test.js` and I'm not able to inspect the firebase-logs as the logs get wiped out after the error.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to send TypeScript directly to the Firebase CLI like this, espeically if it has TS-specific syntax in it, such as the `as UserDocumentData` part of what you show here.  The TypeScript needs to be transpiled to plain JavaScript before a nodejs interpreter will make sense of it.

You might want to do some digging to see what the error was that caused the output "Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error."  I believe the Firebase CLI sends debug info to a log file in the current directory.